# How do I get the type of T inside a generic method?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following generic method:

```
protected IEnumerable<T> GetAnimals<T>() where T : Animal
{
  // code
}
```

I may call this method using `GetAnimals<Dog>()` or `GetAnimals<Cat>()` where the Dog and Cat classes inherit from `Animal`.

What I need is to get the `typeof(T)` to find that the current method is executing with `Dog` or `Cat`. I've tried so far:

```
protected IEnumerable<T> GetAnimals<T>() where T : Animal
{
  bool isDog = typeof(T) is Dog ? true : false;
}
```

This `typeof` returns `Animal` and not `Cat` or `Dog`, so this is my issue.

One solution would be to create a method in `Animal` like `WhatIAm()` and implement it in Dog as `return typeof(Dog)` but I believe this is a bad solution.

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if you need a type check inside your generic method, maybe you are having the wrong approach / design. Generally this is considered bad design.

The actual solution to your problem:

```
bool isDog = typeof(T) == typeof(Dog);
```

Note that `T` must match `Dog` exact. Classes deriving from `Dog` are excluded.

A better approach might be:

```
bool isDog = typeof(Dog).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
```

Also, you don't need the ternary operator.

Comment: didn't know about the `IsAssignableFrom()` thanks for the intel +1

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the types directly

```
bool isDog = typeof(T) == typeof(Dog) ? true : false;
```

`typeof(T)` doesn't return `Animal`, it returns a type instance. `is` operator compares if the `Type` is compatible with `Dog` which is not because there is no relationship between Dog and type.